# Understanding server log files

Tags: wordpress, authentication, logging

I have these records in my log file:

GET /wordpress/wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 200 6294

GET /wordpress/wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 302 -

Are these successful logins?

Answer (score 0):

Http status code 200 means "OK" and Http status code 302 means "FOUND" (Found is a common way of performing URL redirection back to your application after successful login).

These status codes do suggest a successful login, but more information about the application's authentication and authorization mechanism is needed in order to be sure.